# How do I make it clear that someone is going through something, like Obito and not like someone pushed through something?

Tags: creative-writing

There’s a car and it’s going through a fence and I say “the car did not go under, around nor over the fence but through it” how do I say that in a way that conveys that the car went through it like how Harry Potter went through platform nine and three quarters and not like the car rammed through it

Comment: The car went through the fence as if the fence were a mere hologram, a mirage, doing no damage to either car or fence. However, voting to close, this is asking what to write.

Answer (score 5):

A couple solutions for you:

**Change verb**

Verbs characterize the action. Try one different from "going". "Phasing" would be my first choice.

> The car phased through the fence

**Detail**

Make very clear to the reader what's going on. Instead of simply

> The car went through the fence

say

> The car went *through* the fence, not as a wrecking ball goes through a wall, but in the same way we go through mirrors in dreams

(The metaphors could use some work, but you get the gist of it)

**Establish a precedent**

If your reader knows what to expect, you can let them do the heavy lifting of creating the picture. I believe this is what JK does in the HP books. The first time Harry goes through the platform, she describes in detail what happens. After that she just says he got through. There's no need to describe it again. Harry also sees other people going through first, establishing precedents.

Comment: Just an addition: That car went through the fence without hitting it at all. That car went throuh the fence without damaging it.